# VB .Net GeckoFx doesn't load videos from iframe

Tags: vb.net, iframe, video-streaming, geckofx

As the title says I'm trying to show videos from an iframe tag in a **VB** Application, but my GeckoFx browser only shows a white screen and an alert window pops up, saying `c is not a registered protocol`.

My Code:

```
File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath & "/Dump/site.html", My.Resources.Ifame)
Gecko1.Navigate(Application.StartupPath & "/Dump/site.html")
Gecko1.Visible = True
```

My.Resources.Iframe:

```
<html>
<body>
<IFRAME SRC="http://www.mp4upload.com/embed-qdj03qmk52rj.html" allowfullscreen="true" FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=640 HEIGHT=380></IFRAME>
</body>
</html>
```

I've already implemented

```
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.Default("extensions.blocklist.enabled") = False
```

into the loading event of the Form.

I also tried the same html with the normal Webbrowser, but it doesn't work either. It is not a problem with the hoster, because the same error shows up every time regardless of the iframe source.

Btw I'm using GeckoFx 29.0 with the matching version of xulrunner and there aren't any other errors.

---

### Update

Thanks Tom for helping me (see him down in the comments). I just needed to change

```
Gecko1.Navigate(Application.StartupPath & "/Dump/site.html")
```

to

```
Gecko1.Navigate("file://" & Application.StartupPath & "/Dump/site.html")
```

Comment: I guessing, given the error message, your have a path like c:\... - if so try making it file://c:\... instead.